# Is there any way to transfer windows files by automatically convert in zip format and then to aws s3 bucket in an automate way daily

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, automation, cloud

Looking an automate process so that files will compress automatically and then transfered to aws s3 bucket from local system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a script that will:

- Zip the files
- Use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws s3 cp` command to copy the file to Amazon S3